# live migration of a virtual machine to a different machine

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I am trying to do live-migration using KVM (libvirt).
VM is called host1 and dest. IP address is 10.81.1.9. However, running the following command gives me an error that I am not sure what this exactly means.

`virsh migrate --live host1 10.81.1.9`

`error: no connection driver available for No connection for URI 10.81.1.9
error: Reconnected to the hypervisor`

These two machines (src and dest) have a common nfs which stores the img file. any idea what this error means and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a valid [URI](http://libvirt.org/uri.html) for the [migration](http://libvirt.org/migration.html) to be successful. What kind of transport is available depends on your setup, but try `qemu+ssh://10.8.1.9`.